# Running script with defined parameters as set in settings

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create something that when the script is run it reads the parameters that have been set in there.

For example loading a custom sidebar where the user can enter details or parameters to the run the script with. These parameters will remain until they are changed but shouldn't be required every time you run a script that uses these parameters.

A sort of like settings menu.

I have seen something similar in some addons that have been made can someone please point in right direction on how to go abouts doing this.

I already have the scripts running succesfully just need a UI where the parameters can be entered and set. I would like to avoid reading it from a sheet in the spreadsheet if possible.

Edit:

I see that there is a getscriptproperty available that is available to all users:

so far I have got update (2):
HTML:

```js
function showside(){

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('body'))
}

function setProperty(objectForm){
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(
    {a1: objectForm.a1 , 
  a2: objectForm.a2, 
  p1: objectForm.p1,
  p2: objectForm.p3})
  return 'Updated'
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  function readProperty(){
  
  var settings = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(), keys = settings.getKeys()
  Logger.log('running')
  for (var i =0;i<keys.length;i++){
  document.getElementbyID(keys[i].toUpperCase()).value = settings.getProperty(keys[i])

  }
}

function handleFormSubmit(objectForm){
google.script.run.setProperty(update).setProperty(objectForm)
}

function update(update){
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = 'Updated!';
      }
</script>

    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body onload="readProperty()">
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
  
  a1<input type="url" id="a1" value="" />
  a2<input type="url" id="a2" value="" />
  a3<input type="url" id="a3" value="" />
  P1<input type="text" id="P1" value="" />
  P2<input type="text" id="P2" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
  
  
</html>
```

Comment: so now I have done this but it doesn't seem to be reading the properties set already let alone write new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough approach; Improvise from here;

Read comments inside the loadScript();

```js
document.getElementById("formWithData").onsubmit = loadScript();

function loadScript() {
   // get data from submitted form
   // this way script will re-run with data based on what u give in the form
}
```

```html
<form id="formWithData">
<input type="text" placeholder ="enter condition 1">
<input type="text" placeholder ="enter condition 2">
<input type="text" placeholder ="enter condition 3">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the comments I have just revised my question from what I have just learnt, from reading your idea as well as googling a lot. and this is what I have come up with so far

Comment: go to the html of the sidebar; there must be some html component via which u want to trigger script (say by form submit or by button click); if form submit use above approach; if button click replace 'onsubmit' in above script with 'onclick' and replace form id with id of the element that u are clicking